# Reducer not able to group by key for different mappers

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Use-case :

1. File 1 contain impression data which contains trackerId + other fields
2. File 2 contains click details contains trackerId + clicked

I am using different mappers for above two and one reducer but it seems reducer is not able to combine both files data.

```
package com.hadoop.intellipaat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.MultipleInputs;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

import com.google.common.collect.Lists;

/**
 * This job will combine click and impression on TrackerId
 * 
 * @author raghunandangupta
 *
 */

public class JoinClickImpressionDetailJob {

    public static final String IMPRESSION_PREFIX = "IMPRESSION_PREFIX";
    public static final String CLICK_PREFIX = "CLICK_PREFIX";
    public static final String SEPERATOR = "~";

    private static class ImpressionMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            /**
             * Excluding header
             */
            if (!(value.toString().indexOf("accountId") != -1)) {
                String words[] = value.toString().split(",");
                if (words.length > 18) {
                    context.write(new Text(words[18].trim()), new Text(IMPRESSION_PREFIX + SEPERATOR + value.toString()));
                }
            } else {
                context.write(new Text(""), value);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ClickMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        @Override
        protected void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text>.Context context)
                throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String words[] = value.toString().split(",");
            if (words.length > 18) {
                context.write(new Text(words[18].trim()), new Text(CLICK_PREFIX + SEPERATOR + value.toString()));
            } else {
                context.write(new Text(""), new Text("1"));
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ImpressionClickReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        @Override
        protected void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text>.Context context) {
            try {
                System.out.println("=========="+key.toString());
                if (key.toString().length() != 0) {
                    List<Text> myList = Lists.newArrayList(values);

                    for(Text t : myList){
                        System.out.println("#######"+t.toString());
                    }
                    System.out.println("@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@");
                    if (myList.size() == 2) {
                        if (myList.get(0).toString().indexOf(IMPRESSION_PREFIX) != -1 && myList.get(1).toString().indexOf(CLICK_PREFIX) != -1) {
                            String line = myList.get(0).toString().split(SEPERATOR)[1] + ",1";
                            context.write(key, new Text(line));
                        } else if (myList.get(1).toString().indexOf(IMPRESSION_PREFIX) != -1
                                && myList.get(0).toString().indexOf(CLICK_PREFIX) != -1) {
                            String line = myList.get(1).toString().split(SEPERATOR)[1] + ",1";
                            context.write(key, new Text(line));
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            // conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress", "true");
            // conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.codec",
            // "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec");
            // conf.set("mapreduce.map.output.compress.codec",
            // "org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec");
            // conf.set("mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.compress.type",
            // "BLOCK");
            Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "IMPRESSION_CLICK_COMBINE_JOB");

            job.setMapOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
            job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);

            job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
            job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

            job.setReducerClass(ImpressionClickReducer.class);

            FileInputFormat.setInputDirRecursive(job, true);

            // FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
            // job.setMapperClass(ImpressionMapper.class);

            /**
             * Here directory of impressions will be present
             */
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]), TextInputFormat.class, ImpressionMapper.class);
            /**
             * Here directory of clicks will be present
             */
            MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[1]), TextInputFormat.class, ClickMapper.class);

            FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[2]));

            job.waitForCompletion(true);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Any leads will be appreciated.

Eg. `File 1   [trackerId1,record1]`
    `File2    [treackerId1, Clicked]`

In reducer I am getting :

`trackerId,[record1,record1]` ideally it should be `trackerId ,[record1,clicked]`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely with this line in the reducer:

`List<Text> myList = Lists.newArrayList(values);`

The main thing to remember is that `Iterable<Text> values` is reusing the `Text` object it gives you as you iterate. So you might be adding two `Text` objects to the array, but they are pointing at the same object.

If you look at how `Lists.newArrayList()` works, it just adds objects to the array, without creating a new one.

So if you're going to use `Text` objects you need to create a new one each time you add a value to the array. This is typically a reason why people use Strings in cases like this. A quick check to see if this is the problem would be to change this code to something like:

```
List<Text> myList = new ArrayList<Text>();
for (Text v : values) {
    myList.add(new Text(v));
}
```

Thus, you create a new `Text` each time.

Comment: Thanks I got it later.